# Missing one condition to display a string

Tags: shell

I am working on a small script that simply takes a parameter and read the output of `ls -l` and displays the user and name of the file that start with that parameter.

For exemple :

```
$> ls -l | ./script.sh "ok"
John   ok_file
Mark   ok_test
```

Here is what the script looks like :

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                   

while read hello
do
    name=$(echo $hello | cut -d' ' -f9 | grep $1)

    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        log=$(echo $hello | cut -d' ' -f3)
        echo -n $log' ' && echo $name
    fi
done
```

It works just fine but I am missing one condition : it doesn't display the file that STARTS with the parameter but any file that CONTAINS it.

How could I change this script to add this condition?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'grep' command uses a regular expression to match text. Use a '^' before the expression, to match from the start of the line. So, you can change the line

```
name=$(echo $hello | cut -d' ' -f9 | grep $1)
```

to

```
name=$(echo $hello | cut -d' ' -f9 | grep "^"$1)
```

and you should get the expected result.